# Error installing python package with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I'm new to Python and trying to start with Python in Visual Studio 2015 as I'm familiar with VS. I could successfully create a sample program but when I'm trying to install a package rpi.gpio using pip, it gives me the following error. I'm using Python 2.7 64bit and Visual Studio 2015. Could anyone please help?

```
----- Installing 'rpi.gpio' -----
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting rpi.gpio
  Using cached RPi.GPIO-0.5.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: rpi.gpio
  Running setup.py install for rpi.gpio
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\30201610\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-6yfuyd\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\30201610\appdata\local\temp\pip-ovjyww-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\RPi
    copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\RPi
    running build_ext
    building 'RPi.GPIO' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\source
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsource/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\source/py_gpio.obj
    py_gpio.c
    source/py_gpio.c(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(109): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(113): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(194): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(218): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    source/py_gpio.c(270): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(272): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(326): error C2373: 'output': redefinition; different type modifiers
    c:\users\30201610\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6yfuyd\rpi.gpio\source\constants.h(29): note: see declaration of 'output'
    source/py_gpio.c(326): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
    source/py_gpio.c(340): warning C4047: 'return': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    source/py_gpio.c(387): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(389): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(391): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    source/py_gpio.c(393): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\30201610\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-6yfuyd\\rpi.gpio\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\30201610\appdata\local\temp\pip-ovjyww-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\30201610\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6yfuyd\rpi.gpio
----- Failed to install 'rpi.gpio' -----
```

Comment: Please consider copying the error into a code block instead of showing us an image.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question with the error text.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused. Why are you installing a library that controls GPIO on a Raspberry Pi on Windows?

Comment: Good question. Because Visual Studio can't be installed on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I have this same issue actually. I just want to install this library on Windows because I'm writing code for my Pi in Visual Studio and I want to get rid of the error it triggers. Obviously not going to "use" the library in Windows, but I want it there as reference for my Python code, like all other pip-installed modules.

Comment: There is no solution for installing `RPi.GPIO` on Windows besides actually porting the code, or using Linux. If you want to port the code: a Windows port of `mman` should be found somewhere, `open` on Windows has no `O_SYNC` flag, `arpa/inet.h` includes should be replaced by `winsock2.h` and probably many more. Setting up a Linux docker container or a VM will be a lot easier IMO.

Answer (score 2):

[relevant sourceforge issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/156/)

> RPi.GPIO is designed to run on a Raspberry Pi running Linux only.  - Ben Croston (Maintainer)

Comment: sort of what I suspected, well there goes auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

You probably not needed the rpi.gpio package to remote access the pins of the Pi. Pin factory is missing if no remote pigpio server configured via the PIGPIO_ADDR environment variable, so it falls back to localhost, where, well, there is nothing.

- apt install pigpio to the Pi
- On the Interfaces tab of the Pi Configuration enable remote GPIO
- start the daemon with sudo pigpiod
- pip install the gpiozero and pigpio packages to the Windows machine
- set the PIGPIO_ADDR environment variable like SET PIGPIO_ADDR=192.168.1.3
- start your Python app on the PC while the Pi is accessible via the
  network.

This way I was able to use exactly the same code on my PC as on the Pi.

If you use ANSI control sequences, consider using the new [MS Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) from te store

More details, alternatives, remote OSs: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html